# importScripts in service worker

Tags: service-worker, indexeddb

I am trying to use IndexedDB through [Jakes Archibald's promise-based IDB lib](https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb) by `importScripts` but as soon as I select "offline" through Chrome Dev Tools I am getting `An unknown error occurred when fetching the script`. A funny thing that's happening is that even if shut down my localhost server my app works fine (I have the browser cache disabled through Chrome Dev Tools) on my service worker installed browser but on another, of course, it doesn't.

I've looked into these https://www.w3.org/TR/service-workers/#importscripts, https://github.com/w3c/ServiceWorker/issues/106 resources but I didn't find an fix to my problem.

Any help/explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you managed to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely to be that you've not cached the `idb.js` file so that the service worker can access it when your app is offline.

Try adding it using `cache.add` (or `cache.addAll` if you are caching multiple files) inside your `install` callback.

Answer (score -2):

Here is a library that i created. It makes using IndexedDB a whole lot easier! completely client-side, no dependencies!

https://github.com/ryanwaite28/promise-db

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I can't see how that is an answer to my question.